# how to set infowindow to cluster icon(count_text) not to cluster markers?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I have added info windows to cluster markers, but I just wanted to open custom info window on tap of cluster Icon, is there any possibilities?
Thanks in Advance.

[image: I want same custom info window to clusterIcon]
[image: implemented infoWindow to markers]